# Как проверить содержит ли строка текст или цифры

Tags: php

Как я могу проверить содержит ли строка текст или цифры и если строка содержит текст то вывести
**Вот так :**

```
    }else{
            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu 
                WHERE Menu_name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'  
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
        }
```

В противном случае вывести
**Вот так:**

```
}else{
            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu 
                WHERE Price LIKE '%".$keyword."%'  
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая функция как `gettype()`, вы можете проверять тип и делать то что вам нужно. Подробнее [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gettype.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $keyword);
```

В $res будет 1 если $keyword содержит **только** цифры и 0 если кроме цифр есть другие знаки.

И sql запрос лучше делать с использованием https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php чем составлением строки.

Answer (score 0):

**Мне это подошло**

```
}else{
            }if (is_numeric($keyword)){
            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu 
                WHERE Price LIKE '%".$keyword."%'  
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";

                }else if (mysql_escape_string($keyword)){

            // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                FROM tbl_menu 
                WHERE Menu_name LIKE '%".$keyword."%'  
                ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
                }
```